# Shift characters (A-Z) in a string by 5 places

Tags: c#, caesar-cipher

There are no syntax errors in this code, and so improvements could be in the areas of performance, maintainability, and usability.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int shift = 5;
            string output = "";
            Console.Write("Input: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (input[i] < 65 || input[i] > 90)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Only A-Z supported.");
                    }
                    int shifted = input[i] + shift;
                    if (shifted > 90)
                    {
                        shifted = 65 + shifted - 91;
                    }
                    output = output + (char)shifted;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Output: " + output);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

##### Suggestion 1

Your `shift` variable can be constant (and you should try and have everything constant unless otherwise). However, it's only used once, so I don't think you lose readability by moving the value into the for loop and removing the variable entirely:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    ...

    // Hardcode the value of 5, rather than referencing shift
    int shifted = input[i] + 5;
    
    ...
}
```

I suppose the argument could be made that storing the shift value in a variable allows you to easily modify the cipher at a later point, but in that case, you'd be better off extracting all of the logic out of `static void Main` and into a function that takes the shift as a parameter anyways!

##### Suggestion 2

This logic:

```cs
shifted = 65 + shifted - 91;
```

can be simplified to

```cs
shifted -= 26;
```

##### Suggestion 3

If you're concatenating a string in a loop, you should use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0). (You'll need to include `using System.Text;` at the top of your .cs file to import `StringBuilder`)

```cs
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

...

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    ...

    // We now append to the StringBuilder, rather than the string
    // Deleted: output = output + (char)shifted;
    output.Append((char) shifted);
}

...
```

Also, a minor suggestion, I'd move the declaration of the output so it's after when you call `Console.ReadLine()`, but before the for loop. This is declaring the variable as late as possible, and only improves (in my opinion) readability (but I know some prefer to declare everything upfront!).

##### Suggestion 4

You should invert the logic of your if statement that checks for null inputs to reduce the overall nesting of the program:

```cs
if (input == null) {
    Console.WriteLine("You didn't provide an input!");
    return; // This is important otherwise it will still try and perform the rotation!
}

...
// Now you can continue, knowing that input is not null
```

##### Suggestion 5

You could replace the for loop with a [foreach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-foreach-statement) loop:

```cs
foreach (char c in input)
{
    // Now you don't have to use `input[i]`, you can just use `c`
}
```

With the foreach loop, you lose the index of the loop (`i`), but you don't use this in your solution, so it's suitable for your use case.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>                     if (input[i] < 65 || input[i] > 90)
> ```

would be more readable as

```
                    if (input[i] < 'A' || input[i] > 'Z')
```

Similarly,

> ```
>                         shifted = 65 + shifted - 91;
> ```

might be either

```
                    shifted -= (1 + 'Z' - 'A');
```

or post math

```
                    shifted -= 26;
```

I would find 26 far more recognizable than `65 - 91`.  Because I know that there are 26 letters in the (Latin1) alphabet.  If you think that it is likely that most of the readers of your code won't know that, then it would be better to use the letters' [character constants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-character-constants?view=msvc-170) to make what you are actually doing clearer.

The 1 to fix the [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error) might require a comment.  But if you use the alphabet size, then you wouldn't need that.  Adding a constant might help:

```
const char AlphabetSize = 1 + 'Z' - 'A';
```

Then you don't need to explain that 26 is the alphabet size.  The constant's name documents that for you.  And now it is less important to document that the 1 avoids a fencepost error, because people can work through the logic themselves.  Clearly we are calculating the alphabet size...what do we need to do to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that could be done to make it more friendly to other users (for example, those that could consume it in an API.)

- Move the shifting logic to a seperate method. This allows it to be reused across multiple codebases and methods.
- Use a `StringBuilder` to improve concatenation performance. This will depend on what string are being shifted, so you will have to profile it and see if it makes sense for your use case.
- Use characters (such as `'A'`) instead of their integer versions to improve clarity.
- Let the user know what character was out of range in the exception.

```
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        const int shift = 5;
        Console.Write("Input: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        var output = Shift(input, shift);
        Console.WriteLine($"Output: {output}");
    }
    private static string Shift(string? input, int shiftAmt)
    {
        if (input == null) return string.Empty;

        StringBuilder output = new();
        foreach (var c in input)
        {
            if (c is < 'A' or > 'Z') throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"'{c}' is out of range (expected character between A-Z.)");

            var shifted = c + shiftAmt;
            if (shifted > 'Z')
            {
                shifted = 65 + shifted - 91;
            }

            output.Append((char)shifted);
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```